# Angular2 mechanism behind array update

Tags: angular

I'm new to Angular2 (started learning weak ago). I'm trying to grasp a concept of observables and data exchange between components.

I created some code where user can input a data in a form.

```
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="string" class="form-control" id="someValue" [formControl]="myForm.controls['someValue']">
      </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This action should:

1. Update a list of elements

   ```
       <ul> <li *ngFor="let val of valsList"> {{ val.someValue }} </li</ul>
   ```
2. Show a counter of elements

   {{counter}}

I created a Plunker with an example of what I have.

http://plnkr.co/edit/pkIpmdS2uOmb7Rf4FfAH?p=preview

Now the thing I don't understand is why the list is getting automatically updated. There must be some kind of binding working but what and how exactly ?

Simmilar approach for counter isn't working.

Regards.

Comment: i will try to answer your question the way i understand it (but i could be wrong). the my-app component template contains the my-grid component. the my grid component has the service injected in the constructor which updates the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using Observable in your application, To know more how component interaction works , you may look [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html)

In the Plunker you are pushing object into `valsList` hence your grid is updating as it is directly binding to valsList object.

However for `counter` you are creating a different instace and updating it hence counter component is not picking up the value.

If you wrap counter into object and use it in the component it will work (as you are not creating new instace of counter just updating the existing object)

Check this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/gYsNVvlw0vz2zVtNf4By?p=preview)!!

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks! Front end programming is stil very new to me. Now I have to figure out how to write the same thing using Observables. Ie. that event is triggering the counter. I found some examples but none were using a bit more complex architecture.